# Consumer Router/Firewall qualities which are compatible with IP phones

Tags: firewall, sip

I use a SIP phone from home over an internet connection to connect to a PBX in the internet.  The internet connection is 50 Mbps down / 10 Mpbs up.

Empirically I have tested several routers and found some router/firewalls allow the SIP traffic to pass through the firewall successfully while others do not allow the SIP traffic to pass, regardless of the settings (SIP ALG on/off, etc).

What qualities of a router/firewall prevent the SIP traffic from transiting?
How can I look for these qualities when I shop for hardware?

Answer (score 0):

Consumer firewalls that allow for installing a custom firmware package like tomato or dd-wrt would allow you to do as you please.